# Geting NoClassDefFound when running maven project using JPA framework EclipseLink/H2

Tags: java, maven, jpa, eclipselink, h2

I'm currently working on a team project. This a maven project working with eclipseLink and h2. I'm the only one on the team with this problem and i can not figure why. I have already deleted .m2 and cloned the project again from git repository. This is the error i get while running the tests.

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/logging/log4j/LogManager

    at eapli.framework.infrastructure.repositories.impl.jpa.JpaTransactionalContext.<clinit>(JpaTransactionalContext.java:49)
    at eapli.framework.infrastructure.repositories.impl.jpa.JpaTransactionalRepository.<init>(JpaTransactionalRepository.java:75)
    at eapli.framework.infrastructure.repositories.impl.jpa.JpaAutoTxRepository.<init>(JpaAutoTxRepository.java:71)
    at eapli.persistence.jpa.JpaCoverageRepository.<init>(JpaCoverageRepository.java:34)
    at eapli.persistence.jpa.JpaRepositoryFactory.coverages(JpaRepositoryFactory.java:54)
    at eapli.presentation.application.CreateCoverageControllerIntegrationTest.<clinit>(CreateCoverageControllerIntegrationTest.java:20)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.junit.platform.commons.util.ReflectionUtils.newInstance(ReflectionUtils.java:443)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:60)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassTestDescriptor.invokeTestClassConstructor(ClassTestDescriptor.java:342)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassTestDescriptor.instantiateTestClass(ClassTestDescriptor.java:289)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassTestDescriptor.instantiateTestClass(ClassTestDescriptor.java:281)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassTestDescriptor.instantiateAndPostProcessTestInstance(ClassTestDescriptor.java:269)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassTestDescriptor.lambda$testInstanceProvider$2(ClassTestDescriptor.java:259)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassTestDescriptor.lambda$testInstanceProvider$3(ClassTestDescriptor.java:263)
    at java.util.Optional.orElseGet(Optional.java:267)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassTestDescriptor.lambda$testInstanceProvider$4(ClassTestDescriptor.java:262)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.prepare(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:82)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.prepare(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:59)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$prepare$0(NodeTestTask.java:83)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:72)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.prepare(NodeTestTask.java:83)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:69)
    at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1257)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$4(NodeTestTask.java:112)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:72)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:98)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:74)
    at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1257)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$4(NodeTestTask.java:112)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:72)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:98)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:74)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:32)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:51)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:220)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.lambda$execute$6(DefaultLauncher.java:188)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.withInterceptedStreams(DefaultLauncher.java:202)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:181)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:128)
    at com.intellij.junit5.JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.java:69)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 50 more


Process finished with exit code 255
```

## EDIT:

I managed to resolve part of the error by reinstalling some dependencies. Still it does not allow me to run the project (the project compiles using mvn test), giving me the following error:

```
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$ReflectUtils$1 (file:/usr/share/maven/lib/guice.jar) to method java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(java.lang.String,byte[],int,int,java.security.ProtectionDomain)
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$ReflectUtils$1
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
```

Comment: You miss log4j in your classpath

Comment: @Jens how can i do that?

Comment: Add it as a dependency in your pom.xml.  Easy stuff.

Comment: And.. where is the code that returns this error?

Comment: @duffymo I've tried already to add it as a dependency, but it is still not working. and also, this is program developed by a team of developers, and it is crashing only on my pc, it's probably a local problem, not related to the pom.xml. thank you anyway

Comment: IntelliJ should tell you what external libraries are loaded.  You can also right click on the pom, generate a dependency diagram, and search inside that for all transitive dependencies.  If IntelliJ tells you there's a problem, believe it.